# Ruby: how to pass an arg to system command during execution

Tags: ruby, unix, system, freebsd

Good day!
It's a very simple question i think but i can't figure out how to handle it. So  i ask you for advice or direction. 
I make a `system` call to unix command and during its execution it asks me to input a string description. How can i do that?
Thank you!

Seems like my problem is solved half a way. To make it absolutely clear can anybody tell me why this code:

```
#/usr/local/bin/ruby19 
#Process.daemon(true) 
exec "/bin/cp src dst"
```

works fine but if  `#` from the `Process.daemon(true)` is removed it does nothing?

Comment: you need to use something like Open3.popen3 to be able to read process output and write to process.

Comment: I have tried Open3.popen3. Looks like just what i need.

Comment: But if i make my script run as a daemon the result is wrong. Is it because of that script became another thread and has another pid? I didn't had a deals with processes before. Need to go deeper.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IO.pipe` and `spawn` (in Ruby 1.9.3) to create a pipe to the other process for writing to it. For example,

```
r, w = IO.pipe
spawn("cat", :in => r)
r.close

# the write to the pipe, which `cat` will read from
w.write("hello\n")
```